# Calculate the prorata weight of a list of numbers (including negative) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, data-science

I am looking for a way to distribute a positive number proportionally to a list of numbers based on their value (higher gets more). Think of it as distributing a fixed bonus amount based on everyone's performance (pnl).

This is simple if the numbers are all positive. The prorata weight of [1,2,3] would be [1/6, 2/6, 3/6]. But I am not sure how to handle the case for something like [-1, 2, 3] in code?

Comment: Seems like you need some additional constraints. Can a bonus be negative? If not, should negative performers get zero bonus, or does everyone get a positive bonus even if their performance is negative? If the latter, what's the principle by which you determine the "consolation" bonus given to negative performers?

Comment: @constantstranger, bonus cannot be negative. Everyone gets a positive bonus even if their performance is negative. For you last question, I’m open to suggestions but maybe something like everyone gets a positive bonus relative to where you are in terms of your ranking among peers?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the clarification in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of additional information: if the weights for [1,2,3] are [1/6, 2/6, 3/6], then for [-1,2,3] they would be [-1/4, 2/4, 3/4].

Example:

```py
def get_weights(p, nums):
    total = sum(nums)
    return [p * num / total for num in nums]
    
print(get_weights(1, [1, 2, 3]))
print(get_weights(1, [-1, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5]
[-0.25, 0.5, 0.75]
```

**UPDATED:**

Based on OP's updated question and comments, one "bonus" policy that could be adopted is:

- allocate a "base bonus" pool from which everyone receives an equal base bonus
- in addition, allocate a "rank bonus" pool from which everyone receives an additional bonus pro rata with their performance ranking
- for the balance of the bonus pool, everyone with positive performance receives an additional bonus pro rata with their performance.

Example:

```py
performance = [-1,2,3,-1]
bonus_pool = 1
base_bonus = 0.1
rank_bonus = 0.1
# rank items in the list `performance` and allocate the rank_bonus pro rata to rank
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(performance)
rank = {x[1][0][0]:(x[0] + 1, x[1][0][1]) for x in enumerate(zip(sorted(c.items())))}
total_rank = sum(v[0]*v[1] for v in rank.values())

pro_rata_bonus = 1 - base_bonus - rank_bonus
total_pro_rata = sum(x for x in performance if x > 0)
n = len(performance)
bonus_base = [bonus_pool * base_bonus / n for k in performance]
bonus_rank = [bonus_pool * rank_bonus * rank[k][0] / total_rank for k in performance]
bonus_pro_rata = [bonus_pool * pro_rata_bonus * max(k, 0) / total_pro_rata for k in performance]
bonus = [bonus_pool * (base_bonus / n + rank_bonus * rank[k][0] / total_rank + 
    pro_rata_bonus * max(k, 0) / total_pro_rata) for k in performance]


print(f'performance   :', end=''); [print(f' {x:5}',end='') for x in performance]; print(f' TOTAL: {sum(performance):5}')
print(f'bonus_base    :', end=''); [print(f' {x:0.3f}',end='') for x in bonus_base]; print(f' TOTAL: {sum(bonus_base):0.3f}')
print(f'bonus_rank    :', end=''); [print(f' {x:0.3f}',end='') for x in bonus_rank];  print(f' TOTAL: {sum(bonus_rank):0.3f}')
print(f'bonus_pro_rata:', end=''); [print(f' {x:0.3f}',end='') for x in bonus_pro_rata];  print(f' TOTAL: {sum(bonus_pro_rata):0.3f}')
print(f'---------------', end=''); [print(f'------',end='') for x in bonus]; print()
print(f'bonus         :', end=''); [print(f' {x:0.3f}',end='') for x in bonus];  print(f' TOTAL: {sum(bonus):0.3f}')
```

Output:

```
performance   :    -1     2     3    -1 TOTAL:     3
bonus_base    : 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.025 TOTAL: 0.100
bonus_rank    : 0.014 0.029 0.043 0.014 TOTAL: 0.100
bonus_pro_rata: 0.000 0.320 0.480 0.000 TOTAL: 0.800
---------------------------------------
bonus         : 0.039 0.374 0.548 0.039 TOTAL: 1.000
```

Comment: The proportion all need to be positive. And how would you code that given a list?

Comment: In your question you wrote "I am looking for a way to distribute a positive number proportionally to a list of numbers based on their value (higher gets more)". Are you now saying that you want to distribute the positive number proportionally to a list of numbers based on their magnitude (in other words, based on their absolute value)?

Comment: @DOt dot Do you need any additional help with your question? If not, please consider marking one of the answers as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

well you'd need to define the weight for negative numbers, the most intuitive way to me would be to take their absolute value over the sum of the abs., something like :

```
total_sum = sum([abs(x) for x in my_list])
weights = [abs(x)/total_sum for x in my_list]
```

but this is just one way to do it, without more information on what you're trying to achieve it's hard to be more precise.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it won't accurately reflect [-1, 1]. In that case, "1" contributed more than "-1" so they shouldn't get the same weight.

Comment: Well then you need to think about which weighing method method makes most sense for your particular use case, you have to understand that you could do virtually anything, you could add the absolute value of the lowest number to all numbers so that you're left with only positive numbers, you could apply x -> exp(x) to all numbers then normalize by the sum of the exponentials (which would heavily favor bigger numbers), there's no single perfect answer.

Comment: I would like a case that every value gets a positive weight relative to its peers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can interpret the values as being measured on a logarithmic scale, then a reasonable approach is to use the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function).  SciPy has an implementation in [`scipy.special.softmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.softmax.html).

For example,

```
In [39]: softmax([-1, 2, 3])
Out[39]: array([0.01321289, 0.26538793, 0.72139918])

In [40]: softmax([-3, 2, 3])
Out[40]: array([0.00180884, 0.26845495, 0.72973621])
```

Because the values are on a logarithmic scale, when all the values are positive, you don't get the pro rata results that you mention in the question:

```
In [43]: softmax([1, 2, 3])
Out[43]: array([0.09003057, 0.24472847, 0.66524096])

In [44]: softmax([2, 2, 3])
Out[44]: array([0.21194156, 0.21194156, 0.57611688])

In [45]: softmax([2, 2.1, 3])
Out[45]: array([0.20732037, 0.22912444, 0.56355519])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work well when the inputs differ from each other a lot. E.g. [3062431, 5729370]

Comment: If those are typical numbers, you should add that to the question.

Comment: I like your answer too btw. thank you